# Photos app will not open, gets stuck at Repairing Library... 5% complete

Tags: photos, photos.app

I have a MacPro 5.1 running macOS Mojave 10.14.6. My Photos library is on a secondary internal drive. It was working a few days ago, but not it will not open. When I try and open it while holding command-option it prompts for a repair of the library, which I do. However, it gets stuck at 5%. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: How long did you wait? Have you tried checking/repairing the drive itself?

Comment: It's been running for over 24 hours. It's stuck.

Comment: OK. Time to test the drive then.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to run "First Aid" but the umount failed - do I perhaps need to boot to recovery mode? I do not have macOS installed on this drive, please note.

Comment: I was able to unmount it, first aid running now... :)

Comment: I'm using Photos.app 3.0 on macOS 10.13 and it's stuck on 104%. fml. And you can't quit it.